# From where magento2 fetches result when we select any option from 'sort by' dropdown on product listing page?

Tags: magento2, cache, sort-by-options

From where magento2 fetches result when we select any option from 'sort by' dropdown on product listing page? Does Magento reassign order for the items instantly or it displays result from cached/indexed file?

Comment: I am asking this because ,on product listing page,  order/sequence of products ['sort by price' applied] getting change after sometimes. If I do full indexing, then it becomes correct. Then after sometimes, order of products goes wrong again. Magento version: 2.4.2

Comment: From indexed tables.